# Trying to translate a MySQL query into a PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm still kinda new to PHP and MySQL and I've tried so many times to do this and I just can't figure out how.

I have a query that returns the results I want in PHPMyAdmin as a straight MySQL query but I'm trying to get this to generate on a webpage using a PHP `$query` and I just can't get the syntax right.

this is the working MySQL query:

```
SELECT fk_toon_no, fk_actor_no, actor_no, actor FROM cartoon_characters, 
characters WHERE fk_toon_no=50 HAVING fk_actor_no=actor_no;
```

The kicker is that I also want to have a variable `$new_toon_id` as the `=` for the `WHERE` statement, so, something like: (but only displaying the row as I will eventually plug this into a table and know how to do that fine)

```
    WHERE fk_toon_no=$new_toon_id
```

`fk_actor_no` is the foreign key of the `cartoon_characters` table to the primary key `actor_no` in the characters table.

I'm trying to get it so that I can print out every character associated with a particular cartoon so it would look something like

```
    (toon id)      (character id #)     (character name)
    ($fk_toon_no)  (actor_no)           (actor)   
    3               5                    Eisenhower
    3               9                    Nixon
    3               12                   Uncle Sam
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think I've included all the relevant information but if I forgot anything please ask.

I'm in desperate need of help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=<<<HERE
SELECT fk_toon_no, fk_actor_no, actor_no, actor FROM cartoon_characters, 
characters WHERE fk_toon_no='50' HAVING fk_actor_no=actor_no;
HERE;
$send=mysql_qyery($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($send))
{
echo $row["fk_toon_no"];
echo "<br />"
echo $row[fk_actor_no];

}
```

This should do the trick.